# Clone someone else's public repo in Github Desktop

Tags: github-desktop

Github Desktop makes it easy for me to clone projects from Github, when they belong to my account (or one of my organizations).

[image: Cloning projects with Github Desktop]

Is there any way for me to clone a public repo belonging to somebody else with Github Desktop?

Comment: no, only **Clone in Desktop** button on the webpage is for that

Comment: @closevoter: GitHub Desktop is used primarily for programming...

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt ?? what else is GitHub for? Noob here.

Comment: @Fandango68 e.g. small datasets https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/pubmed-rct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that from within Github Desktop.

You can use the *Clone in Desktop* button on a Github project's webpage (as Anatoly said).

[image]

Another alternative (without the client of course), is opening a cmd/terminal and using:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Comment: On the github page for the project I click 'Clone or download' and then 'Open in desktop' and nothing happens. So I copied the url `https://github.com/<user>/<project>.git` from 'Clown or download', opened git-bash command line, and did `git clone <url>`, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can drag-and-drop the URL from your browser onto GitHub Desktop. Then it will ask you where to save the files.

Comment: Where are you dropping the URL in GHDesktop? I've tried this six ways from Sunday and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems fork and clone if you use the client. Otherwise use command line tools like @Shameel Abdullah said

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what do you mean by "_Seems fork and clone if you use the client_". That sentence doesn't make a sense to me.